# プログラム内のどの部分でintの"0"を出力するよう指示しているのか

Tags: python, python3

問題のコードは以下の通りです。

```
for y in range(15):
    for x in range(20):
        if(y%4==3):field[y][x]='#'
        elif x%2==0 :field[y][x]=' '
        print(field[y][x], end='')#" 0"と" 0"の間にspace
    print()
```

見る限りどこで0を出力させているのか私には分かりませんでした。
因みに出力結果は

```
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
####################
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
####################
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
####################
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

となります

これが俗に言う「0埋め」の一種なのでしょうか？
([「0埋め」という言葉が出てきたqiitaのURLです](https://qiita.com/chun1182/items/ddf2b6cba932b2bb0d4e#numpyscipy%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6))
初歩的な質問ですがどなたかよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: この前に `field` がどこかで定義されているはずです．そこはどうなっていますか？

Comment: 既に実行していたセルで定義していました。お騒がせしました。。。。。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`field` はそれ以前のセルで定義されていたとのことです。上記のコードより手前で `field` が `0` を要素として持つように定義されていたので、それがそのまま印字されたのでしょう。